# React Auth : Bearer undefined (401 Unauthorized)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, axios

I am using reactJs,i get a 401 unauthorized `Authorization: Bearer undefined` when trying to pass the authorization header from my login page to my home page
this is my index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import axios from 'axios';

axios.defaults.baseURL= 'https://here.herokuapp.com/'
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('auth_token')


ReactDOM.render(
 
    <App />
 ,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

My login page

```
axios.post("api/auth/login",data)
        .then(res => {
           localStorage.setItem('auth_token',res.data.auth_token)
           this.setState({
               loggedIn:true
           })
```

Comment: As a start point, you can log the token before setting it inside the localstorage, check the localstorage if set, log the token when getting it.

Comment: In my log in page ,i can console.log(res.data),but when i type console.log(res.data.auth_token) its undefined

Answer (score 1):

I found out my console structure was `res.data.data.auth_token` not `res.data.auth_token`